# ActionScript - Difference Between Primitive / Non-Primitive Objects for Memory Management?

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-management, garbage-collection, primitive-types

my understanding is that primitive types (*uint, string, Number, etc.*) of a class do not need to be set to null for garbage collection.

for example, i am not required to write this `dispose()` method in the following class:

```
package
{
//Imports
import flash.display.Shape;

//Class
public class DrawSquare extends Shape
    {
    //Properties
    private var squareColorProperty:uint;

    //Constructor
    public function DrawSquare(squareColor:uint)
        {
        squareColorProperty = squareColor;

        init();
        }

    //Initialize
    private function init():void
        {
        graphics.beginFill(shapeColorProperty);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
        graphics.endFill();
        }

    //Dispose
    public function dispose():void
        {
        squareColorProperty = null;
        }

    //Get Shape Color
    public function get squareColor():uint;
        {
        return squareColorProperty;
        }
    }
}
```

if this is true, which i believe it is, what is the difference between objects of primitive types and objects of non primitive types concerning memory allocation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, the most complete and detailed explanation of GC logics in flash player VM is located [in the blog of Alex Harui, written back in 2007](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2007/03/garbage_collection_and_memory.html). Direct link: [GCAtomic.ppt](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/GarbageCollection/GCAtomic.ppt).

[And here are some useful hints on GC from Grant Skinner.](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/garbage_collection.html)

GC logic deals with references and reference counting. And since you can not obtain a reference to a primitive in ActionScript, you can do nothing about GC in this aspect.

**EDIT** Just remembered another [nice set of articles on GC and resource management](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/06/as3_resource_ma.html) by Grant Skinner.

Comment: The link to GCAtomic.ppt is already broken but it looks like someone made it available via Slideshare: http://www.slideshare.net/bufanliu/gc-atomic

Answer (score 1):

The GC removes objects that are not strong-referenced by any object. Primitive typed fields are not referenced at all - their values are directly stored in the the containing object's memory (at least I think so).

I hope it helps.