# What keeps locally scoped objects alive when listeners are registered?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I see this type of apparent magic in all sorts of AS3 code, but here is a reduced example:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;

    public class URLLoaderExample extends Sprite {
        public function URLLoaderExample() {
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
            loader.load(new URLRequest("example.txt");
        } // 'loader' should fall out of scope here!

        private function onComplete(evt:Event):void {
            var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(evt.target);
            trace ("Received data: " + loader.data);
            //unsure if removal below is necessary (since I don't
            //know where 'loader' itself is hiding!)...
                //  - NOTE: this removal is never in the examples!
            loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        }
    }
}
```

As indicated in the code comment, the `loader` variable should fall out of scope after the `URLLoaderExample` constructor.  However... it still seems to be kept alive (not garbage collected) somewhere since the `onComplete` listener/handler is able to receive it cleanly.

**Where is the magic/hidden/global reference to `loader` that keeps it alive so that it can complete it's load operation, and then be handed to the `onComplete` listener/callback?  Can this reference be seen somewhere?**

To help with context... as a similar example, I know that the `loader` instance will have the `onComplete` listener registered.   I also know I need to be careful to use `removeEventListener` at all times (?) to avoid potential memory leaks resulting from stranded listeners.  What concerns me is that I don't understand where the magic `loader` reference is and whether (or when) I need to clean that up.

Is it maybe the `loader.load()` call itself that stuffs `loader` somewhere globally?

Comment: @Nox Noctis - I will definitely be doing so.  No need to nag. :)  However... been busy and am not sure how I'll proceed.  I don't like to accept pseudo-correct answers.  Yours is 100% correct and useful re: GC and general scoping.  Although for the specific URLLoader case, J_A_X is likely correct (testing would be time consuming) on the internal voodoo referencing.  When I return to flash development I'll be looking into it more, possibly merging the answers.

Comment: @Nox Noctis - Or... I could accept reality and that I likely won't have the time to fully test out the magic/hidden reference holding noted by J_A_X... I've done so and accepted your answer with a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example is definitely error-prone, since loader **may** get garbage-collected before loading is finished. When you subscribe to `COMPLETE` event with `onComplete` method, you create a reference **from** loader to your class `URLLoaderExample`. And what you need to make sure GC will no ruin the loader is creating a reference **to** it.

GC never guarantees you timely cleaning though, even when you explicitly kill all the references. ([See this post for resources on GC logics.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570105/actionscript-difference-between-primitive-non-primitive-objects-for-memory-ma/6570257#6570257)) But it **can** garbage-collect a loader in the process if there are no explicit references to it. If you try your test in an app that uses memory (and is not just sitting there doing nothing), you are likely to see this behaviour. And you are much more likely to see loader garbage-collected if you try loading swfs instead of data.

Using weak references does not help here, because when you do so, you tell GC: "feel free to kill what I, the dispatcher, am referencing, I have no pity for it." In your example it would be like: "feel free to kill URLLoaderExample instance if it looses other viable references", which is, well, pointless. [Here's one good article on useWeakReference.](http://gingerbinger.com/2010/07/actionscript-3-0-events-the-myth-of-useweakreference/)

Listeners do not prevent **a dispatcher** from being garbage-collected. An inactive object is one that no longer has any references to it from other active objects. So, if an object itself has references to something external, it does not prevent this object to be removed from the memory.

So, to answer your question briefly: the reference is nowhere, you are just lucky to see loading working correctly. Well, to be completely precise, it's the function activation object (as it is called in ECMA spec), that is used as a scope for local variables and references them. But anyway, it gets disposed on method return, and you can never get a reference to activation object itself (again by spec).

**EDIT** Some more words on who holds who from being garbage-collected. Added due to apparent misunderstanding in comments.

A quotation [from Adobe livedocs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#addEventListener%28%29):

> useWeakReference:Boolean (default = false) — Determines whether the reference to the listener is strong or weak. A strong reference (the default) prevents your listener from being garbage-collected. A weak reference does not.

So, subscription to event creates a reference FROM dispatcher TO listener. And dispatcher is free to go, unlike listener. Listeners do not prevent a dispatcher from being garbage-collected. And dispatcher CAN prevent listeners from being garbage-collected, which is why we have `useWeakReference`.

Comment: This is exactly what I figured was the case... `loader` is still around only because it hasn't been GC'd yet.  The main thing making me think there was some other magic was that the [Adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#includeExamplesSummary) themselves use this exact (albeit bigger) example.  I'm still somewhat skeptical because of examples like that!

Comment: Also - who is actually doing the URL fetching work after the constructor exits?  Is it still the dereferenced-but-not-yet-GC'd URLLoader instance somehow working in the background?  Unfortunately it appears that flash.net (where URLLoader is) is [buried in the player](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2756442) and has no visible source for it, so no help there.  Since it is single-threaded, behind the scenes I would expect that `loader.load` opens the socket, sends the `GET` request, then sets up a callback with an underlying `select` or something, but I'm totally guessing.

Comment: Btw, it's not all that easy to compile a standalone example of a loader being garbage-collected in the process. Apparently, GC's behaviour is dependent on the system's load and capabilities and on Flash Player type (external, plugin or whatever). But a little googling for these problems will show you a lot of posts.

Comment: @Nox Noctis, er, what? "This example is definitely error-prone, since loader may get garbage-collected before loading is finished."  This statement is **false**.  It would only be GC'ed if the weakReference argument of the addEventListener function is set to true.  When an event listener is added, the object that you're currently attaching it do does not get garbage collected.  Each object holds their own handler function references, but if the references are external, the GC *will not* delete them from memory.

Comment: You are wrong, I'm afraid. A quote from Adobe livedocs: `useWeakReference:Boolean (default = false) — Determines whether the reference to the listener is strong or weak. A strong reference (the default) prevents your listener from being garbage-collected. A weak reference does not.` So, subscription to event creates a reference FROM dispatcher TO listener. And dispatcher is free to go, unlike listener. Listeners do not prevent a dispatcher from being garbage collected. And dispatcher CAN prevent listeners from being garbage-collected.

Comment: Note: I'm accepting this as the right answer as it is, generally, correct for the general question.  However, in the specific URLLoader case, there may be an internal/hidden/magic reference held by the player keeping the instance alive.  Please see J_A_X's answer and commentary.

Comment: I am with Nox Noctis on this.  The key thing to understand is that the pattern is OK if the dispatcher is a display object that is on stage, as its parent display object will maintain a reference to it even if the locally declared dispatcher goes out of scope.  In other cases, such as above, when the dispatcher goes out of scope, depending upon if an event has been dispatched or not one of two things happen : 1) the dispatcher and listener have no references and are GC eligible or 2) the dispatcher, event, and listener all have references but are on a memory island, and are GC eligible.

Comment: Another comment, due to lack of space.  Furthermore, despite the talk of "secret" references, the code above DOES have a bug, since it does not adhere to how Adobe have said things work : i.e. any object that has no references or is on a memory island can be marked for sweep. If a particular runtime just happens to implement a "secret reference" then fine, but it does not mean other runtimes will do the same, it does not make the code correct, and it does not mean the next version of that runtime will do the same.  The correct method is to explicitly maintain a reference to the dispatcher.

Answer (score 1):

When you add an event listener, you implicitly create a reference to the loader object (by default). However, you can remove that by setting the eventlistener to a "weak" reference.

Here's how you'd do that:

```
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete, false, 0, true);
```

The last argument sets "useWeakListener" to true, which means a reference to the loader will not be made. In that case, the loader should be GC'ed.

The important thing to keep in mind is that if you add an event listener with a strong reference, you need to remove it (as you did in the example). If you use a weak listener, you'll need to make the loader a private variable in the class otherwise your callback is in a race situation with the GC.

Here's the documentation on the method: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html

Comment: I'm not sure that this is correct... I'm pretty sure I understand weak references, and don't think it applies here.  Setting `useWeakReference` to true prevents the listener registration from being used as a reference count for the object/instance that owns the listener/callback.  The `loader` object, and it's listener list should be able to drop out of scope with no problem, regardless of what is in the listener list... shouldn't it?  I think you have it backwards.  What I want to know is why `loader` doesn't die... it would be odd if `loader` referencing itself could keep it alive.

Comment: ... unless the listener list is not kept on the event target (`loader` in this case) like I thought, but is kept in some other global location?  That would explain it.

Comment: According to the Flex source code, there's a global EventManager that holds all the references in a centralized place.

Comment: Where do you see the EventManager reference?  I've been digging through the source for such a reference and haven't found anything useful.  I just searched for `EventManager` and can't locate it... I just see various mouse things like `FlowElementMouseEventManager`.  Also [this](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/) is the best online source I can link to... do you have a better source?

Comment: To eliminate any confusion that may result from reading this answer (or my comments above), the [article linked by Nox](http://gingerbinger.com/2010/07/actionscript-3-0-events-the-myth-of-useweakreference/) is an excellent one.  A dispatcher can NOT keep itself alive because the listener is in the dispatcher, too... ie: referencing what I said in my first comment here, `loader` referencing itself (`loader` method as a listener) is definitely not sufficient to keep `loader` alive.

Answer (score 1):

Well man, if your question was why the loader is alive out of scope, here is your answer:

In fact, the loader you see in the Class Constructor Method (CCM) is not the same you see in onComplete: LINE14: `var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(evt.target);`

(I dont know why does people like to put same name to variables, that can be confusing, but it is not in the case now that i will explain)

The magic lies in the `evt.target`. But you should be asking yourself: "What does the `.target` do?" Well it is a instance variable defined by the "Event Object", and it provides reference to the "Target Object".

If you dont know what a "Event Target" is, read this paragraph. The "Event Target" is the object in which the listener registered at LINE9: `loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);` As you can see, it is the loader at the CCM (please dont confuse the loader names) which refers to `new URLLoader();`. Paragraph Conclusion: the  "Event Target" is the URLLoader object referenced by the load local variable at the CCM.

Well, using the .target variable you can have reference to the URLLoader object and then use the reference as you want. In the case, you used the reference to remove the listener. It is okay.

Here is a improved version (just one instance variable that provides reference hapily to URLLoader):

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;

    public class URLLoaderExample extends Sprite {
        private var lalala:URLLoader;
        public function URLLoaderExample() {
            lalala = new URLLoader();
            lalala.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
            lalala.load(new URLRequest("example.txt");
        }

        private function onComplete(evt:Event):void {
            trace ("Received data: " + lalala.data);
            lalala.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        }
    }
}
```

But just to make shure you arent confused with the names:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;

    public class URLLoaderExample extends Sprite {
        public function URLLoaderExample() {
            var blabla:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            blabla.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
            blabla.load(new URLRequest("example.txt");
        } // 'loader' fell out of scope here! and it fell look there

        private function onComplete(evt:Event):void {
            var phopho:URLLoader = URLLoader(evt.target);
            trace ("Received data: " + phopho.data);
            loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers...
If you have any doubts at the casting operation used at `URLLoader(evt.target);` you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your confusion.  The loader variable *does* go out of scope (as in, the reference you were pointing to in memory is not longer needed).  However, because there's still a reference to an external event listener, the loader itself is not GC'ed, which is why you can continue to get the reference of the loader (in the handler, it's getting the target) and will not be eligible for GC until the event listener is removed.

EDIT: 
Sorry, I should of been more clear on the matter.  I should of had more coffee.  When I mean 'external', I mean things like loaders since they're dependent on a browser action.  Now, I can't say this for sure since I've never seen the underlying code for Flash Player, but my suspicion is that if you have any Loader type classes that needs to interact with the browser, there will be an underlining reference (from the player to the loader) which will stop it from being GC'ed.  This is why that you should [always unload your Loaders](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#unload%28%29) or so, this is my understanding of the Flash Player.  I could be wrong, but I've done several tests in the past and I've never seen an *external* listener (in this case Loaders, but I'm wondering if there's any other external listeners that might happen with Air) get GC without being explicit.

Comment: Please see [links I provided above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570105/actionscript-difference-between-primitive-non-primitive-objects-for-memory-ma/6570257#6570257). Main thing to note is that `An inactive object is one that no longer has any references to it from other active objects.` So, if object itself has references to something external, it does not prevent this object to be removed from the memory. Object has to have some references TO it to stay alive.

Comment: @J_A_X: After a lot of study, I'm with Nox Noctis on this one.  When you say "because there's still a reference to an external event listener", you need to ask yourself (as I did) where that reference you are referring to is.  It isn't "external" as you say.  That reference is actually on `loader` itself, and when `loader` falls out of scope, so does the self-reference.  So it can be GC'd.  Although I'm willing to be convinced otherwise :).  If only we could see the behind-the-scenes source code on this... :(

Comment: @J_A_X I've never implied you don't know what you are talking of. :) What I was saying is: it really works this way in Flash Player, and yes I've seen it working this way many times (although I failed to reproduce it clearly this morning on my iMac). You drop all references to a loader, you have it _randomly_ dead. Let's put it this way: I just trust what nice guys like Grant Skinner are saying when I can definitely prove the facts.

Comment: @Nox, I can't say I've seen this behavior before (or after a barrage of tests).  Personally, I don't do function variables for something you need to listen to, but I was more debating the fact that Loaders (and Timers apparently, after I've talk to my friend on the SDK team) don't get GC'ed because they have a reference in the Flash Player (you need to load/start for it not to be GC'ed, need to unload/stop for it to GC).

Comment: @J_A_X Well, it would be really great to know something from the inside. :) I've reproduced this behaviour back in 2006,2007,2008 and answered several questions on the subject at that time. Which is why I'm dead sure it was there (official docs and some nice guys we can trust also confirm that). But things are changing over time, may be now we have a different situation. May be we just lack the information to define it.

Comment: Yeah, wouldn't be surprised if it got fixed in a later version of Flash Player.  They have been doing considerable changes to the underlying memory allocation/GC code.

Comment: All good discussion... end result being that I won't ever allow such ambiguous questions to exist in my code.  eg: In a case similar to my posted code example (although with `Socket` instead of `URLLoader`), I explicitly create a reference to the questionably scoped instance as a property of the the parent class (mapping to `URLLoaderExample` in the example), just to make sure a clear reference exists and the "who is holding a reference to this?" question never arises.

Comment: @J_A_X @Nox  Also... I think the end answer to my question is that we don't know for sure.  It may be that nobody holds a reference to `loader` and it only works works because the GC doesn't collect it fast enough.  It also may be that `flash.net` items are "special" and get special/magic references in the player that keep it alive.  We can't tell with the latter because this code is not open source.  **Do you guys agree?**  Final advice: always make your references explicit and don't rely on implicit references.

Comment: @Russ, no, I've talked to people from Adobe about this and they all said the same: "If it's an async object that needs to talk to the Flash Player, the reference should not be GC'ed until unloaded". But I do agree on the explicit references.

Comment: @J_A_X, I'm unfortunately still confused then.  What *exactly* does "If it's an async object *that needs to talk to the Flash Player*" mean?  In particular the latter italicized part.  Who is holding this reference and how would we identify what things need "to talk to the Flash Player."?  I can guess at a lot of it, but would prefer some explicit info.  It seems magic at the moment.  Is there some sort of display list equivalent where it is sitting?

Comment: fyi - I posted a comment/question [on the Adobe docs for URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html).

Comment: @Russ, Flash Player provides a set of API, either for internal operations or external (like retrieving information from an HTTP request).  That HTTP request *is not* handles by Flash Player, it's handled by the browser.  As such, *any* classes withing Flash that references an external request (any loaders for HTTP request and Timer is based on your OS' timer), the Flash Player will hold a 'secret' reference to it in memory, hence the GC will not collect it.  Clearer?

Comment: @J_A_X Sort of clearer, and I get the gist, except that the boundaries are still hazy.  eg: If an OS timer counts as an external reference, then so should the OS graphics APIs and all I/O.  It seems like this would cover pretty much all instance types.  Maybe if they don't have pending operations (like a socket or HTTP request would) you could argue that there would be no reason to hold a secret reference, but then we're making assumptions on implementation.  Like I say, I'll steer clear of unclear voodoo and keep to explicit references!  Being unclear on how something works is Bad practice.

Comment: @Russ, OS graphics are 'write only', I/O is event based Flash Player listening to OS, then dispatching internally.  From what I've been told, only Loaders and Timers have a secret reference because of how it works with the OS.  I agree about explicit references, you should always do that, but it's good to know about the underlying reason why some of these objects might not GC :)