# AS3 Tween Freezes

Tags: actionscript-3

I started using AS3's Tween function but noticed some strange behavior every once in awhile. Basically, it freezes before it finishes the tween.

This website seems to offer the solution:
http://www.rgbeffects.com/blog/actionscript/tween-freeze-frustrations-avoid-actionscript-tweens-stalling-out/

My program requires that the rotation tween works precisely every time. I like to use the functions adobe put in place but this makes me nervous since it has such a big issue.

Should I be using AS3's tween or some external tween like greensock.com's TweenLite?

Which would be more reliable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely your tween instance is being prematurely garbage-collected, because you don't store a reference to it somewhere. This is a common mistake which you can easily Google for.

Solution: store a reference to Tween instance while it is performing animation to save it from GC.

Follow the link for detailed explanation: [AS3 Garbage Collection, the reason your tweens are ending early](http://www.scottgmorgan.com/blog/index.php/2007/11/18/as3-garbage-collection-the-reason-your-tweens-are-ending-early/).

[Official article on adobe.com](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/programming_animations_as3.html) also mention this problem (see note at the bottom of article):

> Note: Consider variable scope when using the Tween class. If a tween is created in a function, it is important that the variable's scope exists beyond the function itself. If a tween is stored to a variable of local scope, ActionScript garbage collection removes the tween as the function completes, which will likely be before the tween has even begun.

And here are [some links on garbage collecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570105/actionscript-difference-between-primitive-non-primitive-objects-for-memory-ma/6570257#6570257) if you would like to learn more on GC logics.