# Problem in tween method AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

From timerEvent I have called a function[say 'createBall'] ,passing a Variable[ballCount] every time .
In that function[create ball] ,tween have been called and TweenComplete Listener also added . 
Yet times , the tween is not getting completed .Also it's not giving any error .

```
tweenX = new Tween(obj,"x",Regular.easeInOut,nX,this["tile" + String(bombHit_A[nBombCount] + 0)].x,2,true);
tweenY = new Tween(obj,"y",Regular.easeInOut,nY,this["tile" + String(bombHit_A[nBombCount] + 0)].y,2,true);
tweenX.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, function (e:TweenEvent){hitCompleted(e,obj.name,"tile" + String(bombHit_A[nBombCount] + 0),nBombCount)});
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is the same case [as in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605424/as3-tween-freezes/6606489#6606489): your tween instances get prematurely garbage-collected. [Follow the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605424/as3-tween-freezes/6606489#6606489) to know more.

**EDIT** Decided to add some hints right here. Where do you store those `tweenX` and `tweenY` variables? What is their scope? Are they declared in a method? If so, the references are disposed of once that method exits. You need to maintain a viable reference to tween objects for the whole time of their work, otherwise they *may* get garbage-collected in the process (but you can't know for sure whether this will happen or not).