# Does AS3 have a class destructor?

Tags: actionscript-3

My question is as simple as the title, yet googling it didn't give me a simple yes/no answer.

Does AS3 have a class destructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: no, it doesn't. Flash Player virtual machine uses garbage collector concept. You don't have direct control over memory used by objects (except for rare cases like `BitmapData.dispose()` and `ByteArray.clear()`), but you are to do some work to make garbage collecting possible. And there is no way you can have something triggered automatically when an object dies.

[Follow the links to learn more about GC logics.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570105/actionscript-difference-between-primitive-non-primitive-objects-for-memory-ma/6570257#6570257)

Comment: That was the first thing I tried! )) But it's blocked here, message says: "Answer can't contain that content.". What a shame.